# Best way to write series of images to buffer memory

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Is there a way of using `imencode` and `imdecode` to write and read **series of images** generated in the program into a global buffer?

I'm using `cv::Mat` to read my images. I don't want to use `vector<Mat>` and arrays of `IplImage*` since I'm having some issues with them?

Comment: You are "having issuses" with `vector<Mat>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the data of all the images stored contigously in a single large buffer. Of course this won't work with an array (or vector) of `cv::Mat`s, since they are just wrappers that allocate the image data memory themselves.

This is still achievable using `cv::Mat`s. You first allocate the whole buffer, of course with a size appropriate to contain all the images, and then use the [`cv::Mat` constructor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#cv-mat-mat) that accepts a pointer to user allocated data:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

With an appropriate `data` pointer for the individual sub-images. This way the `cv::Mat` is just a lightweight wrapper around your own image data, wherever it may be stored. But of course now you are responsible for managing (allocating and freeing) the image data storage and providing storage in the correct size.

But keep in mind that this only stores the image data (pixels) in a large contigous buffer. The image properties (like width, height, bit-depth) are stored in the `cv::Mat` objects. So I'm not really sure if this global buffer storage would really buy you anything in performance or useability, maybe if the images a are very (very!) small. And of course you loose `cv::Mat`'s resource management facilities, since you manage the image memory now and need to keep it in sync with the image's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the images?

Or are you trying to write a series of images into a single animated gif or tiled image?

Comment: Maybe this would be better fit as a comment. And I guess it's the latter case he wants to achieve, judging on the words *global buffer*.